# Simple linq query using group in order to return a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a data table of users and another table of user_ratings.  It is a one to many relationship so the they are joined by `UserId`, the users table being the primary key and the user_ratings having the foreign key relationship. Each user_ratings has a column called rating_value and its filled with an int, negative or positive, and it gets summed together to be calculated as the user's rating. I want to be able to pull ratings for each user depending on the date for given ratings.  Here is what I have so far with my linq statement, but I don't think it is right.

```
var profiles = from userprofs in Ent.UserProfiles
               join userratings in Ent.UserRatings on userprofs.UserId equals userratings.UserId
               where userratings.DateAdded >= drm.Start
               group userprofs by userprofs.UserId into g
               select new { ... };
```

Not really sure where to go from here, I'm not sure if I'm using the group correctly.  I want to be able to iterate through this collection later to be able to display each user and his or her associated rating based of the sum of the user_ratings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the information you wish to know about the ratings is aggregate information (sum, average, count, etc) then you can do the likes of this:

```
var profiles = from userprof in Ent.UserProfiles
  join userrating in Ent.UserRatings on userprofs.UserId equals userratings.UserId
  where userrating.DateAdded >= drm.Start
  group userrating by userprof into g
  select new {g.Key.UserID, g.Key.UserName, Count = g.Count(), Avg = g.Avg(r => r.RatingValue) };
```

Note that I changed the plurals to singular names, since we define linq queries in terms of each individual item (UserProfiles is plural, and userprof each item "in" it).

This has a nice straight-forward conversion to SQL:

```
SELECT up.userID, up.userName, COUNT(ur.*), AVG(ur.ratingValue)
FROM UserProfiles up JOIN UserRatings ur
ON up.userID = ur.userID
WHERE dateAdded > {whatever drm.Start is}
GROUP BY up.userID, up.userName
```

If we want to be able to get into individual ratings, this does not match too well with a single SQL query, we could do:

```
var profiles = from userprof in Ent.UserProfiles
  join userrating in Ent.UserRatings on userprofs.UserId equals userratings.UserId
  where userrating.DateAdded >= drm.Start
  group new{userrating.RatingValue, userrating.SomeThing} by new{userprof.UserID, userprof.UserName};
```

This would give us an `IEnumerable<Grouping<{anonymous object}, {anonymous object}>>` that we could iterate through, getting a new `Key.UserID` and `Key.UserName` on each iteration, and being able to iterate through that in turn getting `item.RatingValue` and `item.SomeThing` (that I added in for demonstration, if we want just the value it would be an `IEnumerable<Grouping<{anonymous object}, int>>`) like this:

```
foreach(var group in profiles)
{
  Console.WriteLine("The user is :" + group.Key.UserName + " (id: " + group.Key.UserID ")");
  foreach(var item in group)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.SomeThing + " was rated " + item.RatingValue);
  }
}
```

However, the problem with this, is that there isn't a nice single SQL query that this maps to. Linq will do its best, but that'll mean executing several queries, so you're better off helping it out:

```
var profiles = from item in (from userprof in Ent.UserProfiles
  join userrating in Ent.UserRatings on userprofs.UserId equals userratings.UserId
  where userrating.DateAdded >= drm.Start
  select new{userrating.RatingValue, userrating.SomeThing, userprof.UserID, userprof.UserName}).AsEnumerable()
  group new{item.RatingValue, item.SomeThing} by new{item.UserID, item.UserName}
```

This has the same output as before, but the translation into SQL allows for a single query to be made, with the rest of the work being done in memory. 99% of the time, dragging some work into memory like this makes things less efficient, but because the previous doesn't have a single SQL query it can map to, it's an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
from userprofs in Ent.UserProfiles
join userratings in Ent.UserRatings on userprofs.UserId equals userratings.UserId
where userratings.DateAdded >= drm.Start
group new{userprofs,userratings} by userprofs.UserId into g
select new { userId=g.Key, userRating=g.Sum(i=>i.userratings.rating_value) };
```

`GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping`. An `IGrouping` is basically an `IEnumerable` with an extra `Key` property that contains the property that was used to make the grouping. If you `Sum` the `rating_value` of the grouping, you're there.

Comment: very close, but the i.rating_value is supposed to come from the userratings table and currently i tried what you had here, but it only gives me columns in userprofs

Comment: if you create an anonymous object you can carry though to the select. see my edit.

Comment: I assume that you need to pull more than just the userId from your UserProfiles row, otherwise the join is redundant. You've already got a userId in your userratings column,