# Linq query to store one to many collection in List object

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables (Application and Hazard) with a one to many relationship.

I want to store the list of Hazards to a List object in my ViewModel.

applicationVm  (greatly simplified to just show the collection):

```
 ...
 public List<Hazard> Hazards { get; set; }
```

LINQ query (greatly simplified to just show the collection):

```
  IQueryable<ApplicationVm> applVms;
  applVms = from app in _db.Applications
    ...
    join hz in _db.Hazards on app.Id equals hz.ApplicationId into hzr
      from hzrd in hzr.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ApplicationVm { ..., Hazards = hzrd };
```

Intellisense shows the error 'cannot covert source type Hazard to target type `List<Hazard>`' on the Hazards = hzrd in the select.

How do I write this LINQ query.

PS I do not want to return applVms as a list since I'm lazy loading.

Comment: Hi, this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Comment: @Dr. Stitch As I said in the OP my code samples have been simplified, I have dozens of properties in the ViewModel that are being populated in the LINQ query so selectmany is not at all appropriate.  I couldn't even use it if I tried since  it is not a recognized symbol in this syntax.

Comment: Any way i hope this works:  applVms = from app in _db.Applications
    select new ApplicationVm { ..., Hazards = (from h in _db.Hazards where h.ApplicationId = app.Id  select   h)  }; I haven't tried it before. :P

Comment: You need to grouping like new{hzrd} by new{app.Id }, can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133473/simple-linq-query-using-group-in-order-to-return-a-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it and it works.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Application> application = new List<Application>();
            List<Hazard> hazard = new List<Hazard>();
            int appID = 1;
            int hazID = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                application.Add(new Application() { AppID = appID, AppName = string.Format("AppName{0}", i + 1) });
                hazard.Add(new Hazard() { HazID = hazID, AppID = appID, HazName = string.Format("HazName{0}", hazID) });
                hazID++;
                hazard.Add(new Hazard() { HazID = hazID, AppID = appID, HazName = string.Format("HazName{0}", hazID) });
                hazID++;
                appID++;
            }

            IEnumerable<AppHaz> appHaz = from app in application
                                   select new AppHaz { AppID = app.AppID, Hazards = (from haz in hazard where haz.AppID == app.AppID select haz).ToList() };

        }
    }

    class Application
    {
        public int AppID { get; set; }
        public string AppName { get; set; }
    }

    class Hazard
    {
        public int HazID { get; set; }
        public int AppID { get; set; }
        public string HazName { get; set; }
    }

    class AppHaz
    {
        public int AppID { get; set; }
        public List<Hazard> Hazards { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: He is doing lazy loading, do not want to use ToList()

Comment: It is just a POC. There is always room for improvement. :)

Comment: please refer last line : PS I do not want to return applVms as a list since I'm lazy loading.

Comment: This works and it preserves the Left Outer Join even without the `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.  I'll have to test to see if using `.ToList()` in the sub-query undoes lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
from hzrd in hzr.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ApplicationVm { ..., Hazards = hzrd };
```

The first line basically flattens the result of the group join, thus `hzrd` is of type `Hazard`.

To get the desired result, remove the first line and change the second like this

```
select new ApplicationVm { ..., Hazards = hzr.ToLIst() };
```

Comment: This works also and also preserves the Left Outer Join even without the `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use navigation property app.Hazards?

Anyway, this should work:

```
_db.Applications.GroupJoin(_db.Hazards, a=>a.Id, h=>h.ApplicationId,(a,hzds)=> new ApplicationVm {...,Hazards = hzds,...})
```

Also maybe your List should be IEnumerable (sorry I'm out of the computer so I couldn't test it)

Comment: it seems that he doesn't want to used LINQ method syntax.